# How to use Pandas to select from database and local dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sas, proc-sql

Using SAS, I commonly use proc sql to create a dataset reading from a database. Later I can again use proc sql to query both from the database and from the first local dataset i created.

How does one do this in Python (using Pandas)?

Say in SAS, I run:

```
proc sql;
create table work.dataset1 as
select * from dbtable1;
run;
```

And then I can use this dataset to keep querying my database, as:

```
proc sql;
create table work.dataset2 as
select a.*, b.* from work.dataset1 a, dbtable2 b;
run;
```

I Python I have this code:

```
df1 = pd.read_sql_query("select * from dbtable1", conn)
```

And would like to be able to reference df1 in later queries, like:

```
df2 = pd.read_sql_query("select a.*, b.* from df1 a, dbtable2 b", conn)
```

But this does not seem to work.

Does anyone know how this can be done using Python/Pandas?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_sql_query` will not be able to do this.  You could first run a SQL query on your database to create a dataframe object from `dbtable2`, and use `pandas` methods to run queries on your multiple dataframes.

There is also a Python library called `pandasql` that allows you to query `pandas` dataframes using SQL syntax.  So in your case, it would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df1 = pd.read_sql_query("select * from dbtable1", conn)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query("select * from dbtable2", conn)

pysqldf = lambda q: ps.sqldf(q, globals())
q = """select a.*, b.* from df1 a, df2 b;"""
final_df = pysqldf(q)
```

Comment: Thank you Alexk! This was just the answer I was looking for.